# ¿Cómo puedo obtener datos de una variable en Angular 4?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

¿Cómo puedo obtener datos de una variable en Angular, puede ser un ID, luego esos datos que obtuve, utilizarlos para enviarlos en un formulario?

mi **`.ts`**

```
onUpdate() { 
    this._Filtros.updateArticulo(1, this.catalogo.identificador, 
                                 this.catalogo.nombreCatalago,
                                 this.lineaUpd.clave, 
                                 this.lineaUpd.nombre)
.subscribe(successCode => { 
           this.statusCode = successCode; 
           console.log(successCode); });
           } -> Quiero cachar "this.catalogo.nombreCatalago"
           guardar un ID que viene ahí y después, 
           utilizar ese ID junto con otros datos de un formulario. 
           Ese ID no se ve pero sí debo mandarlo junto con otros dos datos.
```

Mi HTML

```
<td>
    <label class="linea{{idx}}">{{resultado.clave}}</label>
    <input type="text" form="CreateForm" value="{{resultado.clave}}" class="linea{{idx}} oculta form-control" [(ngModel)]="lineaUpd.clave">
</td> 
<td>
    <label class="linea{{idx}}">{{resultado.nombre}}</label>
    <input type="text" form="CreateForm" value="{{resultado.nombre}}" class="linea{{idx}} oculta form-control" [(ngModel)]="lineaUpd.nombre">
</td>
```

Comment: onUpdate() {
    this._Filtros.updateArticulo(1, this.catalogo.identificador, this.catalogo.nombreCatalago, this.lineaUpd.clave, this.lineaUpd.nombre)
    .subscribe(successCode => {
      this.statusCode = successCode;
      console.log(successCode);
    });
  } ->Quiero cachar "this.catalogo.nombreCatalago" guardar un ID que viene ahí y después, utilizar ese ID junto con otros datos de un formulario. Ese ID no se ve pero sí debo mandarlo junto con otros dos datos. Gracias.

Comment: agregalo a la pregunta y elimina el comentario por favor, y creo que necesitare tambien el html

Comment: <td><label class="linea{{idx}}">{{resultado.clave}}</label><input type="text" form="CreateForm" value="{{resultado.clave}}" class="linea{{idx}} oculta form-control" [(ngModel)]="lineaUpd.clave"></td>
          <td><label class="linea{{idx}}">{{resultado.nombre}}</label><input type="text" form="CreateForm" value="{{resultado.nombre}}" class="linea{{idx}} oculta form-control" [(ngModel)]="lineaUpd.nombre"></td>

Comment: debes quitar la etiqueta value="{{resultado.nombre}}"  esto ya no es necesario debes agregar los valores por el ng-model es el imput ya eso no se utiliza en angular

Comment: Esa etiqueta "value" la tengo porque estoy recuperando datos que quiero mostrar en el campo "text" pero al darle clic, como también tengo un "ngModel", éstos se me borran y es lo que no quiero, que se borren.

Comment: eso asignalo al ngModel y no tendras problemas

Answer (score 1):

intenta

```
this.statusCode = successCode.json();
```

si tú quieres puedes cambiar el nombre de la variable 'successCode' a 'response'.

Comment: @JackNavaRow gracias! la costumbre, perdón

Comment: Lo voy intentar así, gracias.